# Apache mod_wsgi memory cache with multiple daemon processes

Tags: python, django, apache, django-rest-framework, mod-wsgi

I have a fairly large Django REST Framework API WSGI website, with 60,000 endpoints. This is deployed to servers running Apache 2.4.6 with Python 3.6.8 and `mod_wsgi` 4.6.2. I've implemented several tricks (such as lazily loading models) which have made it very fast. The only exception to this is when it is first published: it takes about five minutes to spin up whenever we publish a new version to our integration or production environments. That's fine for us, as subsequent page loads are nearly instant. I am assuming this is because elements of the Django project, such as the URL dispatcher for the 60,000 endpoints, get cached in memory.

However, if I change the the `processes` value to anything other than the default of `1`, every page takes the ~5 minutes to load. Here's the relevant part of my current `VirtualHost` configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  TimeOut 600

  ServerName mysite-develop.wharton.upenn.edu

  # Set to the GLOBAL Application Group
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  # Pass Authorizations through to the WSGI app for Django REST Framework Token Auth
  WSGIPassAuthorization On

  WSGIDaemonProcess mysite-develop-https processes=1 python-home=/var/django/mysite/sites/mysite-develop/venv request-timeout=600 user=mysite group=mygroup
  WSGIProcessGroup mysite-develop-https
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/django/mysite/sites/mysite-develop/config/wsgi.py process-group=mysite-develop-https
  <Directory /var/django/mysite/sites/mysite-develop/config>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there any way to get the advantages of the memory caching while running multiple `WSGIDaemonProcess`es? Are my assumptions correct on why this might be happening?

As the initial process after a publish starts up, I can watch the process in `top` until it completes, with about 3.4 GB of memory reserved. This is acceptable for the speed boost, I'd just like to be able to say to have two `WSGIDaemonProcess`es each with their own 3.4 GB memory pool, if necessary.

Comment: *60,000* endpoints? Are you doing something odd like enumerating every ID separately in urls.py?

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's 60,000 separate underlying tables of data, permissioned for individual subscribers. We build the models, serializers, and views by introspecting PostgreSQL. The 60,000 endpoints are categorized and permissioned at the schema level, which gets passed through to Django REST Framework (LDAP backs both PG and Django). Yeah, it's a beast. :)